# gcc: installation problem, cannot exec 'as': No such file or directory

Tags: compilers, c, sgi

How do I compile my code that I have typed on my SGI Indy computer? I have already tried to install the GCC/G++ compilers, but when I run my application, I get the error that says:

> gcc: installation problem, cannot exec 'as': No such file or directory

Do you know where 'as' would possibly be at so I can run my source code?

When it tried to run the code, I typed

```
gcc -o Game Game.cpp
```

I am having to use a C++ file for my C code because stdio does not exist in my computer, and cstdio uses stdio. IOStream was my last most bright option, so I error message above.

I do not really know what I am doing when I installed gcc from SGI's website. I just winged it...

P.S. the capitalization is exactly how it is written on the screen.

Comment: "as" is the assembler.

Comment: Don't know how you did install gcc, but `as` is part of the GCC binutils package. If you bootstrapped and compiled gcc from source, it should also be somewhere in the source tree.

Comment: A proprietary unix like IRIX would also have its own assembler (and linker etc.) and gcc could be configured to use that one instead of GNU binutils.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that stdio does not exist on an Indy?  http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/IRIX/man3/printf.3s.html

Comment: @ChrisStratton I guess gcc just does not know where it is... Do you know where the 'as' executable would be in a normal installation? Thanks! - rjhwinner03

Comment: Wild guess. Your Game.cpp does specify `#include <stdio>` instead of `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: If you type `as` on the command line, is it found? `as` is the assembler. If it's installed, you'll need to tell `gcc` where it is when you install `gcc`. If it's not installed, you'll need to get it and the Irix equivalent of the other programs in *binutils*.

Comment: No, 'as' is not found... And I have tried #include<stdio.h>

Comment: When I installed binutils, I get the same issue: 'as' cannot be found... Do you have a definite tutorial?

Comment: Added some more suggestions to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The SGI builds I have seen require you also have the MIPSpro tools installed on your Irix system as gcc does not include an assembler.

It is possible to cross compile a gcc and binutils for Irix on a PC however you'll still need the headers and libraries so I am not sure you can avoid needing MIPSpro or the IDF/IDL developer library CD-ROMs even then. You will probably also need a matching libg++.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the start of an answer. Run this command:

```
gcc -print-search-dirs | grep '^programs:'
```

That will tell you where gcc thinks **as**, the assembler program, ought to be. Then run

```
find / -name as -print
```

That will tell you where it actually is, if you have one installed.

If you don't have an **as** anywhere, you could try the downloadable MIPSPro CD ISO files on archive.org. It's not clear if you need a license file to run MIPSPro's **as**, but if you do, you're probably stuck, because those license files have to be generated for specific machines, and I don't think anyone has the generator for that since the remains of SGI abandoned Irix.

Another place to try is [irix.cc](http://irix.cc/), which seesm to be where the Irix people hang  out these days.

Yet another is [winworldpc.com](https://winworldpc.com/product/irix/6522).